# data from one component to other component in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I want to share data from one component to other component.

I have a table in list.component (url path: settings/list) like this

[image]

When I click on View/Edit button, it takes to other component selected.component (url path: settings/selected) which shows the details of the selected row like their name, email address.

list.component.ts

```
  getAccountsList() {
    this.http.get<Company>(environment.company,
      { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'bearer localStorage.getItem("jwt_token")' }) })
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.company = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }

  // Memory optimization trick
  userThumb(index, company) {
    return company ? company.id : undefined;
  }
```

list.component.html

```
    <tr *ngFor="let companyData of company?.companies.data; trackBy: userThumb">
                                <td class="text-truncate">{{companyData?.name }}</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: this can be achieved by using shared service. Refer to the link on how to implement shared service: http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/09/angular-share-data-between-components.html

Comment: How this components refer to each other? they are siblings, or parent-child? or not one of what I mentioned?

Comment: they are siblings.

Comment: As @PraveenKumar said, you can create shared service and pass data via it. Or alternatively, you can emit data to parent and broadcast to another child (if they have the same parent), but this way is not very elegant

Comment: I guess you could even use NgRx store or any flux/redux/mobx framework, pretty solid if your project is big enough.Contrary to popular belief/convention you can use it incrementally also in a project, not just globally

Comment: @yer, if they are siblings. Can you post the complete html.

Comment: Pass the data as input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of **list of items** to **item** selection, i personally prefer to pass the id of the selected item on the path.
It's simple clean and well explained in Angular docs.

**What you need to do**

**On the list component**:
- when you select ViewEdit, you get the id of the selected item and put it on the path

```
 goToItemDetails(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['/item-details', id]);
}
```

**On the details Component:**
when you init the component, you get the setted id

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id'];
       // a service that calls item by it's id from the database
    });
```

You can find more details on this [link](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html)